# Calculate probability that the damages to a car exceeded $10$

Tags: probability

Damages to a car in a crash are modeled by a random variable $X$ with density

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} c(x^2-60x+800), \; \; \; \; 0 < x < 20 \\ 0, \; \; \;\ \; otherwise \end{cases} $$

Where $c \in \mathbb{R}$. A particular crash is insured with a deductible of $2$. This car was involved in a crash with resulting damages in excess of the deductible. What is the probability that the damages exceeded $10$?

#### Attempt

Here what confuses me is the introduction of deductible. Do we need to find

$$ P(X > 10 | X > 2 ) $$ ??

the question tells that the crash damages excedeed the deductible which is $2$ . Now we know this is just

$$ \frac{ P(X>10) }{P(X>2)} = \frac{ \int_{10}^{20} f(x) }{\int_2^{20} f(x) } = .. $$

no need to find $c$ since it will cancel out. But, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

P(X > 10) = 4000c/3
P(X > 2) = 5184c
hence
required probability
= 4000/(3 * 5184)
= 0.257201

Thanks